# mouseOver() funny behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very curious as to why the blue `<div>` disappears when I mouse the mouse off the title, as opposed to only disappearing when the mouse if off the *whole* `<div>`.

```
$("#yw1 .portlet-title").mouseover(function(){
    $("#yw1 .portlet-content").slideDown('fast');
});


$("#yw1").mouseout(function(){
    $("#yw1 .portlet-content").slideUp('fast');
});
```

[Here's a demo jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhmeL/1/)

Comment: please also post the code related to your question with the question

Comment: the code is in that link I've provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because `mouseout` events *bubble*, that is to say, when you mouse out of any child, the ancestors will still recieve the event. You can fix this by checking the target against the current target (`this`). [Here's an updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/ZhmeL/2/)

```
$("#yw1").mouseout(function(e) {
    if(e.target === this) {
        $("#yw1 .portlet-content").slideUp('fast');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of mouseout.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is mouseout events get bubbled and it hides. Use `mouseneter` and `mouseleave` events to solve this.

```
$("#yw1 .portlet-title").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#yw1 .portlet-content").slideDown('fast');
});


$("#yw1").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#yw1 .portlet-content").slideUp('fast');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhmeL/10/)**